# Font size in table cell

Tags: tables, fontsize

I am using this code in Pandoc tempalte to create simple table

```
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}  p{15cm}}
     \Huge $title$ & $abstract$
\end{tabular}
```

with straight forwards intentions of having one cell with huge text and other one with smaller text.

But it results in:

[image]

I was hoping, that the top line of '1S' will be in same height as in the other cell.

What am I missing?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39043/134144, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104067/134144

Comment: Try using `m` instead of `p` in column types.